# Django Admin method returns multiple instances instead of one

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a very simple model:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("name", max_length = 128)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Store(models.Model):
    store_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(unique = True)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete = models.CASCADE, null = True, blank = True)
```

which is displayed in the admin by:

```
@admin.register(Product)
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ["name", "get_stores"]

    def get_stores(self, obj):
        s = [s.store_id for s in Store.objects.filter(product = obj)]
        if s:
            print("store -- product:", s, "--", obj)
        return s
```

and leads to the error, that I see every product in the list of products as often as I have stores for it. Output:

```
store/product: [457, 11, 17] -- Cake
store/product: [457, 11, 17] -- Cake
store/product: [457, 11, 17] -- Cake
```

(exactly the same in the admin product list). How can I avoid multiple appearances? Currently there are 3 stores and only 1 product in my database.

[image]

Comment: You are seeing the primary keys of the stores here. `.store_id` will show the primary keys of the `Store`s which refer to `obj`.

Comment: So far so good. But why do I see them 3 times and not only one time?

Comment: because there are three stores that have the `obj` as product?

Comment: you are printing s which is an array for all stores
Show us what is the command you ran for this output

Comment: I thought `get stores()` is being called ONCE per product (`obj`) and not once per product per store - I want to get all stores for one product.

Comment: I added a screenshot. There is only one product in the database right now (cake), but several stores (and the cake is available in 3 of them).

Comment: @GauravJain no command other than the print. I understand that there are three stores with `obj` as `product` but how can I display it only once?

Comment: `obj` is the instance. But then you are using .filter() which can return multiple objects. Why wouldn't you just use `'store_id`' in list_display? What do you want to return?

Comment: I want to see the stores that have a product listed in the products list. If I understand you correctly you mean `list_display = ["name", "store_id"]` - but `store_id` is not in the model `products`?

Comment: I don't quite get your question. Do you wanna list the product or the stores that have the product?

Comment: I have one product "cake" and I want to display all the "stores" that have "cake". But right now this code displays n times "cake" if the number of "stores" that have "cake" is n. I want to end up with ONE line: `cake \t 457, 1179383, 1179384` not three (as it is now).

Comment: Have you checked that your database has only one `cake`? It might be because of data duplication.

Comment: yes, only one cake exists. In fact only ONE product exists at this time.