# Django Admin: Give initial data to form field

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

I need to manually add an entry to the database via the admin panel, but the admin should not be able to set all the values:

```
#models.py
class Product(models.Model):
    price = models.DecimalField("price")
    status = models.PositiveIntegerField("status")
    name = models.CharField("name", max_length=31, unique=True)

## tried:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.initial['status'] = 2

#admin.py
class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ["price", "name",]

@admin.register(Product)
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = ProductForm

## tried:
    def get_changeform_initial_data(self, request):
        return {'status': 99}
```

Admin should be able to create a `Product` and give it a `name` and `price`, but the `status` value should be set to `0`. I already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44420379/django-admin-override-displayed-field-value) approach and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8112859/django-how-do-i-add-data-to-a-modelform-subclass-before-validation), but no success.

I tried:

1. Using an `__init__` method to add initial values
2. `get_changeform_initial_data()` method to add a status.

I always end up with `sqlite3.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: _TEST_Product.status`.

**edit**: I know this can be done by setting a default value in the model, but this is not what I am looking for - I want to set this in the admin.

Comment: Why won't you simple set `status = models.PositiveIntegerField("status", default=0)`?

Comment: my example was over simplified, I fixed that. I do not want a default field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**

Since you don't want to use the `default` field, you should try this approach from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/753722/15065639).

```py
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = ProductForm

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.status = 0
        super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

---

Why don't you just use the `default` field?

```py
status = models.PositiveIntegerField("status", default=0)
```

Comment: I made an edit for my post, I do not want to use the default setting in the model. I know this is a valid option.

Comment: You sir, just solved a headache for me. Thank you very much! can I motivate you to take a look at [my other django-admin headache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65616204/django-admin-method-returns-multiple-instances-instead-of-one?noredirect=1#comment116012327_65616204) as well?